# Extract Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I often use the 'Extract Interface' feature of Resharper for my existing classes, but is there a way to do this for other types where I do not have the source code, just a reference, using resharper or any other tool?

Comment: I don't here ReSharper here, but an idea would be to navigate to the gutted 'source code' and extract the interface from there. You could also go to the same gutted source code, copy it, and edit it (possibly using some basic macroing) to get the result you want.

Comment: Not sure how this could be done but that ReSharper's Extract Interface doesn't work on decompiled code is natural since this refactoring implies changing the code that it's applied to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...Decompile the the dll/type maybe using the in built DotPeek in ReSharper 7.x, then copy and paste the code from the decompiled class to a new local class in your project, then refactor -> extract interface.

The temp class code does not even have to compile, just extract the interface and delete this "temp" class, then add all the using statements to the interface to make it compile.

Hope this helps.

Atif